# Create React small application/page on Wordpress page link?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, api, rest

obviously I've googled and found couple of tutorials uses headless wp with react at front and wordpress as backend but I want to have one page to be displayed and edited on elementor but the second page will be react small app. Tell me how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also what did you tried so far to solve your problem and what went wrong?

Comment: Thank you stuart. I have found an answer and posted it as well for someone who have the same logical isse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is to someone who is new to research of embedding react to wordpress. What I couldn't sort out that how will I use react with WordPress as One page will run with elementor and second page will run through react.

Solution I found is this article:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-embed-a-react-application-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: While this may answer the question, "link only" answers are not good for Stack Overflow. What happens if that link is no longer available in the future? This answer will become invalid.

Comment: Now one issue I'm facing on this is that I am unable to see the react Logo which is a static image, I have also added homepage link to my package.json